# Retrieving size of an element using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have two text boxes detailing the position of something on a canvas, only I want the values in the text boxes to be a number in the range 0 to 1 representing a percentage of the width/height.

I need to some how convert that percentage into margin value. However I am not sure how to do this without breaking the MVVM pattern and accessing the "canvas" from the ViewModel to get it's size.

For example, if the canvas is 100 wide and the X position is 0.1 then I need the left margin to be 10.

I thought about using a command and sending the canvas width/height as an event argument but I am not sure where I would bind this.

XAML

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Position" Width="75"/>
    <TextBox Height="25" Width="50"
             Text="{Binding Path=X, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <TextBox Height="25" Width="50"
             Text="{Binding Path=Y, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</StackPanel>

<Grid Height="300" Width="550">
    <TextBlock FontSize="18" FontFamily="Arial"
               Opacity="{Binding Path=Opacity}"
               Margin="{Binding Position}">
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

ViewModel

```
public double X
{
    get { return Model.Position.X; }
    set
    {
        if (Model.Position.X != value)
        {
            Model.Position = new Point(value, Model.Position.Y);
            OnPropertyChanged("Position");
        }
    }
}

public double Y
{
    get { return Model.Position.Y; }
    set
    {
        if(Model.Position.Y != value)
        {
            Model.Position = new Point(Model.Position.X, value);
            OnPropertyChanged("Position");
        }
    }
}

public Thickness Position
{
    get { return new Thickness(Model.Position.X, Model.Position.Y, 0, 0); }
}
```

Comment: have you tried adding a setter to your position property? i could imagine no binding listening is added, if the clr surface of a class does not provide a setter. on first glance i would expect your sample to be working

Comment: @AndreasMüller The above does work in that if I use an absolute position (i.e. put 100 in for X). However I want to be able to put in 0.1 and have that translate to 100.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution was to use a `MultiBinding` sending the needed information as the values:

```
<Setter Property="Margin">
    <Setter.Value>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyMultiConverter}">
            <Binding Path="X"/>
            <Binding Path="Y"/>
            <Binding ElementName="Canvas" Path="ActualWidth"/>
            <Binding ElementName="Canvas" Path="ActualHeight"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

MyMultiConverter then implements `IMultiValueConverter` and returns a `Thickness`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question, I think you just need to use a converter. You can find more info how to implement it here: http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html

Comment: Does the converter provide access to the element calling the converter?

Comment: Yes look at the example provided, this is pretty straight forward.

Comment: Your provided example does not discuss the converter parameter. I have done some further research and this may be suitable.

Comment: The problem with this approach is you cannot bind to a converter parameter, so for example I cannot send the width with: `ConverterParameter="{Binding ElementName=Canvas, Path=Width}"`